# How to check for ending period in Excel?

Tags: excel

What formula can I use to check if there is a period on the end of my cell. If there isn't add one. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this formula next to your cells you want to check (I used A1 as example).

`=If(A1<>"",If(Right(A1,1)=".",A1,A1&"."),"")`

If A1 is not empty (`A1<>""`) Then:
    If the right most digit (`Right(A1,1)`) is a period `="."`, then return A1.  If not a period, then add a period to the text `A1 & "."`.

otherwise, if the cell is empty, just leave the space empty (`,"")`).

Comment: Perfect Mr. Bruce Wayne ;) if I drag down, it will add a period in empty cells, anyway to not do that?

Comment: @TreyCopeland - D'oh! I forgot to account for that. I have edited the formula and it should work now.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. That did it!